# Hice una barra de busqueda en django y quiero que cuando el resultado no se encuntre me envie un mensaje

Tags: python, django, django-views

estoy desarrollando una app web como si fuera una red social solo de posts entre usuarios, he hecho una barra de búsqueda para que los usuarios puedan buscarse y seguirse entre si, hasta ahí todo bien, pero ahora quiero que cuando el usuario que buscan no este registrado que le salga un mensaje de no resultados, lo he intentado pero no he podido, agradecería mucho de su ayuda. Aquí les dejo el código de la función de la barra de búsqueda

```
def searchbar(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        search = request.GET.get('search')
        user = User.objects.all().filter(username=search)
        user = User.objects.get(username = search)
        posts = user.posts.all()
        return render(request, 'searchbar.html', {'user': user, 'posts': posts})
```

Comment: El mensaje se te enviara a ti como administrador o lo mostrará al usuario. Es el ultimo solo hay que editar el template. Tambien dices que te envie un mensaje "Te refieres al correo"

Comment: No, no es por correo. Quiero que cuando el usuario busque un nombre de usuario no valido o ne registrado aun, en vez de salirle la pagina de error que le salga un mensaje en la pagina que diga: "Usuario no encontrado", eso es lo que quier si me podría ayudar le daría mil gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
def searchbar(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        search = request.GET.get('search')
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=search)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse("Usuario no encontrado")
        posts = user.posts.all()
        return render(request, 'searchbar.html', {'user': user, 'posts': posts})
```

Puedes reemplazar el `HttpResponse` que es texto plano por un render de una plantilla también.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta fue la que me llevo a llegar a una solución, lo único que cuando usaba el HttpResponse me dejaba la pagina en negro, asi que lo que hice fue que me redirigiera al feed y apareciera una notificación arriba donde dijera: Usuario no encontrado